# got list of undefined values in semantic ui search dropdown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, semantic-ui

I am using `semantic ui` in my `rails + angular` application, and i have a search dropdown, and when i type in letter `s` i get a list of `undefined` values in my dropdown, and for other single letters everything works fine.
Interesting thing is that no request to server goes when i type in letter `s`.I am unable to figure out the reason behind it. Below is my code, please help.

javascript code:

```
$('.ui.product.search').dropdown({
    fullTextSearch: true,
    preserveHTML: false,
    debug: true,
    saveRemoteData: false,
    sortSelect: true,
    match: 'text',
    regExp: {
        escape: /[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g,
    },
    apiSettings: {
        url: '/gpr/v1/product_codes/search?name={query}',
    },
});
```

rails controller action:

```
def search
  # byebug
  search_query = ""
  if not params[:name].blank?
    search_query = "%#{params[:name]}%"
  end
  @product_codes = ProductCode.where("H3Description LIKE ?", search_query)
  #render json: {results: @product_codes }
end
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="two fields">
    <div class="field">
        <label><%= t 'asset.create.h3' %></label>
        <select name="products" class="ui product search dropdown" ng-model="asset_details[0].type_details[$index].crop">
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'll try working on it,can you create a plunk for me pls

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess here. Are you sure your escape regExp is correct?

Comment: @gilango removing regExp does not make any difference.

Comment: can you console.log the output when you type the letter `s`?

Answer (score 2):

Your chosen regex setting is the same as the default, so adding/removing those lines shouldn't cause any change in behaviour.

Setting up a slightly [simpler example in Codepen](http://codepen.io/dwightgunning/pen/dpQjWx) using the same code you provided shows that a single "s" character will be sent through to the search API:

```
$(function() {
    $('.ui.product.search').dropdown({
    fullTextSearch: true,
    preserveHTML: false,
    debug: true,
    saveRemoteData: false,
    sortSelect: true,
    match: 'text',
    regExp: {
        escape: /[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g,
    },
    apiSettings: {
        url: '/gpr/v1/product_codes/search?name={query}',
    },
 });
});
```

The fact you're getting `undefined` results would suggest that your search API is responding with data that the Semantic UI can't process in a meaningful way.

Alternatively it's also possible your Angular application is somehow getting in the way. For instance if there are watchers on the model field that's bound to the the input, the input value maybe being changed out and causing the Semantic UI dropdown to misbehave.

I would temporarily remove `ng-model` directive attribute from the input to first get the dropdown search working correctly. Then re-add the model binding and proceed to debug your NG app from there.